# Windows Powershell Export-CSV column/row value as filename

Tags: powershell

I'm having a problem with Powershell. I need to import a csv file, format it and export it.

Now one of the fields is the same value on every line so I want to name the export file the same as a cell value.

I am importing the csv with

```
    Import-Csv c:\tmp\200114.csv
```

Formatting the output with

```
    Select-Object @{expression={$_.code}; label='ID NUMBER'} etc etc but one of the fields being DESCRIPTION
```

Then exporting with:

```
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\tmp\test1.csv
```

So basically I want to  name the file something like the following where DESCRIPTION is the Field name and the row is 1(as they are all the same):

```
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\tmp\@{expression={$_.DESCRIPTION[1]};}.csv
```

But I just get:

Export-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Delimiter'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and tr
y the command again.

Ideally I could like the file name to be:

Todays Date - DESCRIPTION Column ROW 1 Value.csv

### Many thanks for any input....

### SAMPLE DATA:

ID NUMBER,NAME,ADDRESS 1,ADDRESS 2,CITY,STATE,ZIP,Spare,PHONE #,DESCRIPTION,Spare,Spare,VALUE
1,Name 1,address 1,address 2,city 1,state 1,zip 1,,Phone 1,CC098-1,,,NCV
2,Name 2,address 2,address 3,city 2,state 2,zip 2,,Phone 2,CC098-1,,,NCV

---

Thanks, I am very grateful for this. I am struggling to get this working though. It must be to do with:

```
    Select @{n='ID NUMBER';e={$_.code}}, @{n='DESCRIPTION';e={...}}
```

I Don't know the Select command and can't find anything on it, I can't even see how the n= & e= etc are doing. I trimmed it down to:

```
    $csv = Import-Csv c:\tmp\200114.csv | Select-Object @{expression={$_.code}; label='ID NUMBER'} | $filename = "$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd') - $($csv[0].DESCRIPTION).csv" | $csv | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

but I just get errors:

Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:108

```
    + $csv = Import-Csv c:\tmp\200114.csv | Select-Object @{expression={$_.code}; label='ID NUMBER'} | $filename  <<<< = "$
    (Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd') - $($csv[0].DESCRIPTION).csv" | $csv | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Please add some sample data from the CSV files.

Comment: Sure, I've had to put dummy data in, but the headers are correct:

Comment: `select` is an alias for `Select-Object`. When creating [calculated properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) you can use either `@{name=...;expression=...}` or `@{label=...;expression=...}`. `name`, `label` and `expression` can be abbreviated as `n`, `l` and `e` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the processed CSV in a variable:

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\tmp\200114.csv | Select @{n='ID NUMBER';e={$_.code}},
         @{n='DESCRIPTION';e={...}},
         ...
```

Construct your filename:

```
$filename = "$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd') - $($csv[0].DESCRIPTION).csv"
```

Then export the data:

```
$csv | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks, I am very grateful for this. I am struggling to get this working though. It must be to do with: Select @{n='ID NUMBER';e={$_.code}}, @{n='DESCRIPTION';e={...}} I Don't know the Select command and can't find anything on it, I can't even see how the n= & e= etc are doing. I trimmed it down to      ---- $csv = Import-Csv c:\tmp\200114.csv | Select-Object @{expression={$_.code}; label='ID NUMBER'} | $filename = "$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd') - $($csv[0].DESCRIPTION).csv" | $csv | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation   ----- but I just get errors. exp only allowed first line...

Comment: @Paul Please don't post code in comments. It tends to become unreadable. Update your question instead. Also add the exact error you're getting.

Comment: @Paul Why did you make a pipeline of the 3 statements? I didn't tell you to do that.

Comment: Sorry ran in the ISE and your correct it does work. I didn't realize this was possible, I've always run from the command & piped statements..... Thanks so much(New to Powershell I usually use AWK).

Comment: Could you tell me how to specify a path for the file with this? I've tried using -Path but I get cannot bind parameter?

Comment: @Paul What path for which file?